# Bash script to store words from file in different variable

Tags: linux, bash

I have a need to store words form file in different variable. Like I have a file `test.txt` containing below content:

```
uname : null empty amarjeet sharma
ver   : null 1.2 empty 1.3 1.4
txn   : null 123 124 empty 125
```

What is need is to store the word before colon in one variable and remaining in a array form each line.

Example: `uname` is stored in var and ramaining is stored in `value[]` array

```
var = uname
value[] ={null, empty, amarjeet, sharma}
var1 = ver
value1[] = {null, 1.2, empty, 1.3, 1.4}
etc…
```

Comment: Your file contains only three lines?

Comment: @Cyrus No sir !!!!! it can contain many lines and many columns as per need.

Comment: @AbhijatyaSingh What you are asking for is possible but, given bash's capabilities, it is quite awkward.  You might want to explain more about what you are doing so that people may suggest a more suitable data design or a more suitable language.

Comment: @John1024 sir !!!! I was generating xml files based on the test file input given by some other team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare -A hash  # create associative array
declare -a array # create array

# first part: read file to associative array hash
c=0
while IFS=" :" read hash[$c,0] hash[$c,1]; do
  ((c++))
done < filename

# second part: print hash and array
for ((i=0;i<$c;i++)); do
  # create array from hash with part right from :
  array=(${hash[$i,1]})
  echo "${hash[$i,0]} ->  ${array[@]}"
done
```

Output:

```
uname ->  null empty amarjeet sharma
ver ->  null 1.2 empty 1.3 1.4
txn ->  null 123 124 empty 125
```